# SampleCameraExtension where is the folder saved

Tags: sony, sony-smarteyeglass

Running SampleCameraExtension sample and looks like it is working. But I can't find the folder where the files are saved to

Answer (score 0):

If you have "save to SD Card" checked, the files will be saved in /mnt/shell/emulated/0/SampleCameraExtension.

Comment: what about on the phone? Are you referring to laptop?

Comment: I have motorola 2014, no sd card, internal memory only. Should I specify path to somewhere else.